# Multithreading - C - Duplicate Static Variable

Tags: c, multithreading

is there anyway to duplicate some static variable each time a thread make access to them?

I post a simple example:
Module `testF.c`

```
#define <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include "testF.h"

#define MAX_THREADS 10

int *var;

void  testF( void *arg ){ 
    int a,N,i;

    a = (INT_PTR)arg;
    N = (int)(10000/(int)(a+1));
    var = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i<N; i++)
        var[i] = (int)a;
    _endthread();
}
...
```

And in another module `main.c`,

```
...
#include "testF.h"

int main(void){
    HANDLE   hth[MAX_THREADS];
    DWORD   dwExitCode;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
         hth[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthread( testF, 0, (void*)i );

    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hth, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for(i = 0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++){
        GetExitCodeThread( hth[i], &dwExitCode );
        printf( "thread 1 exited with code %u\n", dwExitCode );
        CloseHandle( hth[i] );
    }
}
```

In the this example the variable i would like to duplicate is `*var`.

I've seen that functions like `rand()` give always the same result if called from different thread, so I think that there should be a way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thread-local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage).

Comment: You are welcome! If this answers your question, you should click the checkmark on the left to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `rand()` generally use thread local storage to maintain intercall state on a per-thread basis. This is what you would need to do instead of using a language construct like static. Your other option is to supply the variable into the thread start function, instead of using a global or static.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer.
The problem is that the library i'm working on is too big and it's too much dangerous to modify some code in those modules.